# Set custom radio button field in jira through rest api c#

Tags: c#, jira

I'm trying to set the value of a custom radio button field that has 3 possible options: Yes, No or none. I'm using the Dapplo c# Jira SDK.

I've tried everything going from using "name" to "value" to "id" but nothing seems to work, I always get back "Could not find valid 'id' or 'value' in the Parent Option object".
Note that I want to set the field value by using the ID of the optionset value, not the textual value (like Yes or No) as that might change over time.

These are some of my attempts:

```
        string jsonString = @"{""id"": ""11684""}";
        var myJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonString);
        issueToCreate.Fields.CustomFields.Add("customfield_12093", jsonString); //When I enter the 'jsonString' variable directly I get the same error.
```

does anyone have any idea? This seems much harder than it should be..

Comment: What does "11684" correspond to?

Comment: @WonkotheSane that's the ID of the optionset value "Yes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying about everything, the following finally worked:

```
 var optionSetObject = new {  id = "11681" };
 issueToCreate.Fields.CustomFields.Add("customfield_12093", optionSetObject);
```

I thought the c# anonymous object wouldn't get serialized correctly, but apparently it does. Make sure the "id" value is a string though! If you enter it as an int, Jira won't recognize it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can try: (like use JavaScriptSerializer to serialise an anonymous object):

```
var optionSetObject = new {  id = "11681" };
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var output = serializer.Serialize(optionSetObject);

issueToCreate.Fields.CustomFields.Add("customfield_12093", output);
```